# Cartesian product of sets containing one element.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand the non-associativeness of the Cartesian product. Imagine that you have a set $G = \{ g_1 \}$; why would be $(G \times G) \times G \neq G \times (G \times G)$? I think my confusion comes from the definition of ordered pair, but I am not sure how to use Kuratowski’s definition or any other one when a set is composed by only one element. Is the following product right?

$$( G × G ) × G = \{( g_1 , g_1 ) , g_1 \} \neq
G × ( G × G ) = \{ g_1 , ( g_1 , g_1 )\}$$

I think it is not, and it is the one given in the wikipedia. If I do it graphically, the Cartesian product leads to something different, namely

$$( G × G ) × G = \{( g_1 , g_1 )\} = G × ( G × G ) = \{( g_1 , g_1 )\} $$

What is confusing me here?

Comment: Check again on Wiki; it is $\{ ((1,1),1) \}$ and the same for the other set. The first one is $\{ \{ (1,1) \}, \{ (1,1), 1 \} \}$. Now apply Kuratowski's def again.

Comment: Exactly, @Mauro!  pau, the Cartesian Product of two sets makes ordered pairs, so in the first case, we have $(G\times G)\times G = \{((1, 1), 1)\}.$  In the second case, we have $G\times (G\times G) = \{(1, (1, 1))\}$.  Each set contains one ordered pair, but they are different:  $((1, 1), 1) \neq (1, (1, 1))$

Comment: You wrote that $(G\times G)\times G=\{(g_1,g_1),g_1\}$. This is a mistake because $(G\times G)\times G=\{((g_1,g_1),g_1)\}$. Similarly, $G\times(G\times G)=\{(g_1,(g_1,g_1))\}$. Perhaps, this mistake is what lead  you to conclude that $(G\times G)\times G=\{(g_1,g_1)\}=G\times(G\times G)$, which is not also not correct. I've posted an answer below, which I hope will be helpful. Please let me know if you have questions. I'll be happy to answer them!

Answer (score 1):

**(0)** To simplify notation, let's let $g=g_1$, so that $G=\{g\}$.

Let's also let $h=(g,g)$.

Using Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs, we have that

$$\begin{align*}
(g,g) &=\{\{g\},\{g,g\}\} \\
&=\{\{g\},\{g\}\} \\
&=\{\{g\}\}
\end{align*}$$

So using Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs, we get that $h=\{\{g\}\}$. The important thing to notice here is that $h\ne g$.

**(1)** Let's note that

$$\begin{align*}
G\times(G\times G) &= \{(g,(g,g))\} \\
&= \{(g,h)\}
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
(G\times G)\times G &= \{((g,g),g)\} \\
&= \{(h,g)\}
\end{align*}$$

Since $h\ne g$, it follows that $G\times(G\times G)\ne(G\times G)\times G$.

**(2)** If the Cartesian product were associative, then that would mean that

$$A\times(B\times C)=(A\times B)\times C$$

**for any** sets $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Since the above equation does not hold when we set $A$, $B$, and $C$ equal to our set $G=\{g\}$, it follows that the Cartesian product is not associative.